# Why Python Issues a Key Error When Adding

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add 1 to the ID column so that I may eventually merge these data to [this text file](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/jae/datasets/hsiao003/readme.hcw.txt) which indexes the names of countries. For the merge to work, the IDs must be the same number, though, meaning I need to simply add 1 to the `id` column.

```
import requests, zipfile, io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/jae/datasets/hsiao003/hcw-data.zip'
filename = 'hcw-data.txt'

r = requests.get(url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall()


df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = '\t+' , header=None)

df.columns = ['gdp_' + str(col) for col in df.columns]

df['time'] = np.arange(len(df))+1

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames="gdp", i=["time"], j="id", sep="_")

df['id'] = df['id'] + 1
```

However, Python issues a vague `KeyError: 'id'` error. Why is this? And more importantly, how do I fix this so that I can do what I wish?

EDIT: When I print the dataframe, I see that I have only one column. This makes me suspect I reshaped incorrectly.

Comment: Does `df['id']` exist for you to add one to it in the first place?

Comment: @Pep_8_Guardiola No, I've edited it to reflect that I've reshaped incorrectly. When I print the dataframe, Python recognizes 1 column and 1500 rows, when it should be three columns and 1500 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `pd.wide_to_long` since you read your data from a file with `stack`. However, your problem is you don't `reset_index` after you reshaped the dataframe:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(url, sep='\t+', header=None, engine='python')
        .stack().rename_axis(['time', 'id']).rename('gdp').reset_index()
        .assign(time=lambda x: x['time'] + 1))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      time  id       gdp
0        1   0  0.062000
1        1   1  0.040489
2        1   2 -0.013084
3        1   3  0.010064
4        1   4 -0.012292
...    ...  ..       ...
1520    61  20  0.133400
1521    61  21  0.167034
1522    61  22  0.049144
1523    61  23  0.058841
1524    61  24  0.123800

[1525 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `wide_to_long` transformation sets `time` and `id` as `DataFrame` indices.

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames="gdp", i=["time"], j="id", sep="_")

df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # converts indices back into columns
```

You can use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` to convert `time` and `id` into columns again, thereafter your code does not return a `KeyError` anymore. Hope this helps!